# How do I determine the default action for a Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing

I'm working on a functional test that needs to assert that a certain XHTML tag is present in a certain set of controllers. I'm basically doing this:

```
class ApplicationControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def setup
    @controller = ApplicationController.new
  end
  # [...]
  def test_foo_bar_and_baz_include_stylesheet
    [FooController, BarController, BazController].each do |controller|
      @controller = controller.new
      get :show
      assert_select 'head > link[rel="stylesheet"]'
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that not all controllers have a `:show` action. What I need to do is ask either the controller or the routing configuration for the controller's default action and call `get` with that.

**Update:** [Joseph Silvashy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103739/joseph-silvashy) was right: I ended up separating my controller `get`s out into separate test cases. Solving the "default" route problem was bad enough, until I discovered that some of my routes had conditions attached, and I would have to parse them to craft the correct `get` call. And finally, Rails functional tests don't deal very well with calling `get` multiple times in the same test case, especially when that those calls are hitting multiple controllers. :(

I think the lesson here is one that we all know by heart but sometimes is hard to accept: if the code looks hairy, you're probably doing it wrong. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controllers don't have a "default" view or action, additionally actions can be named anything you want, they don't have to be the standard `index`, `show`, `new`, etc...

I'll probably have to `:get` the appropriate action for each controller you want to test. It's likely each test will be different down the road anyhow, even though right now they all have the same requirement, I think it makes sense to write one for each action regardless.

Comment: So is there no way to programmatically access routing information?

Comment: I seriously doubt the tests will diverge, given the specificity of what I'm testing, so I think my current approach probably is decent.

Comment: Sure you can get your routes from: `ActionController::Routing::Routes`

Answer (score 0):

try to use the respond_to function: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001005
to check if a method exitst.

Comment: `#respond_to?` is certainly useful to keep from trying an action that a controller doesn't support, but it doesn't help me figure out what action a controller will perform by "default" (i.e. according to routes).